# Anticipating fatal errors when using stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Please see the code below:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetPerson

AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
BEGIN TRY
    DECLARE @TestVariable1 AS INT;
    DECLARE @TestVariable2 AS INT;
    SET @TestVariable1 = 1;
    SET @TestVariable2 = 0;
    DECLARE @TestVariable3 AS INT;
    SET @TestVariable3 = @TestVariable1 / @TestVariable2;
    PRINT 'transaction committed';
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK;
    PRINT 'transaction rolled back';
END CATCH
```

I could run this using the command:

```
EXEC GetPerson
```

The transaction is successfully rolled back because you cannot divide my zero.

Now see the code below:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetPerson

AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
BEGIN TRY
    CREATE TABLE #Test
    (
        test INT
    );
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM   #Test;
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM   person.person;
    DROP TABLE #Test;
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM   #Test;
    PRINT 'transaction committed';
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK;
    PRINT 'transaction rolled back';
END CATCH
```

If I run the same comment:

```
EXEC GetPerson
```

then I get an error:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Procedure GetPerson, Line 11
>   Invalid object name '#Test'.
>
> Msg 266, Level 16, State 2, Procedure GetPerson, Line 11
>   Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 0, current count = 1

I understand that not all errors are caught by the TRY clause as explained here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms178592.aspx

> *When RAISERROR is run with a severity of 11 or higher in a TRY block, it transfers control to the associated CATCH block*

My question is: how do you deal with these? I know in my code it is a clear developer mistake to try to select from a temp table that no longer exists.  However, I am wandering if there are other errors I should deal with.

Is it acceptable practice to do this when calling the stored procedure:

```
EXECUTE GetPerson ;

IF @@trancount >= 1
ROLLBACK;
```

Alternatively I could do something like this:

```
EXEC GetPerson
    IF @@trancount >= 1
    INSERT INTO dbLog ("Trancount greater than 1 after running GetPerson")
```

Comment: FWIW, [this](http://rusanu.com/2009/06/11/exception-handling-and-nested-transactions/) may provide some additional insights into transactions and error handling.

Answer (score 3):

Error 208 is a **compilation** error. Your code never run, anything, because it could not even compile. This is the same as asking a C# program to catch a compile error.

Besides, if you want a correct try/catch block that handles exceptions and transaction, see [Exception handling and nested transactions](http://rusanu.com/2009/06/11/exception-handling-and-nested-transactions/):

```
create procedure [usp_my_procedure_name]
as
begin
    set nocount on;
    declare @trancount int;
    set @trancount = @@trancount;
    begin try
        if @trancount = 0
            begin transaction
        else
            save transaction usp_my_procedure_name;

        -- Do the actual work here

lbexit:
        if @trancount = 0   
            commit;
    end try
    begin catch
        declare @error int, @message varchar(4000), @xstate int;
        select @error = ERROR_NUMBER(), @message = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @xstate = XACT_STATE();
        if @xstate = -1
            rollback;
        if @xstate = 1 and @trancount = 0
            rollback
        if @xstate = 1 and @trancount > 0
            rollback transaction usp_my_procedure_name;

        raiserror ('usp_my_procedure_name: %d: %s', 16, 1, @error, @message) ;
    end catch   
end
```

Obviously this will not handle syntax/binding errors (like 208), but at least will handle correct procedures. Remember that checking [`XACT_STATE()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189797.aspx) in the CATCH block is **mandatory**. Consider an error like 1205 (deadlock) where the CATCH block runs *after* the transaction was rolled back. You also need to honor and handle caller's transaction.

Comment: Thanks +1.  I am a little confused.  I will explain the reason for the queston.  I have a stored procedure that takes about two hours to run.  On line one it creates a temporary table.  Recently after about ten minutes of running time it fails with the error: "Invalid object name '#TableName".  Therefore this suggests that it does try to run?